# AFNetworking automatically wraps requests in JSON?

Tags: iphone, json, http, post, afnetworking

I'm having a small problem with AFNetworking.

Im trying to have a simple call to a path with POST parameters (e.g. http://myserver.com/index.php with parameters myParam=1)

I've tried using both AFURLConnectionOperation and AFJSONRequestOperation and on both when i output the "request", it shows {"myParam":1}, as if its packing my request as json, when  actually it should be regular post (the response is JSON , but thats less relevant).

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue except for using NSURLConnection ?

Thank you :)
Shai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set parameterEncoding to AFFormURLParameterEncoding in your AFHTTPClient

Comment: So simple! thanks :) I'm just frustrated by the lack of proper documentation for this library. DO you have any idea where can i find some proper documentation except for the appledoc they release?

Comment: I also wanted to know if i have to use an NSOperationQueue to run a single request (like AFJSONRequestOperation) or can i run it independently ?

Comment: No I don't know any docs. I've the same problem last week and find the solution by reading the code.

Comment: I alway use NSOperationQueue because I think it's easier to use.

Comment: @ShaiMishali Have you seen the [appledoc documentation](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html)? This is the same documentation used in the header files, and linked from the README.

Comment: Yeah i did, its great for finding info on specific functions, but to actually get to work (just moved from ASIHTTPRequest), i couldn't really find any "Getting Started", or anything that could get me right into work, i had to dig a bit to find answers ;-)

Comment: Yeah, we're working on that. As it were, I just wrote up an FAQ that you might find to be helpful: https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

Comment: Great ! it already looks great, can't wait for it to update with more basic stuff - its gonna help many developers :)